# Is there a way to prevent wild Pokémon from running away in battle?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I recently failed to catch a shiny Pokémon after it ran away from a battle. I know previous Pokémon games have had moves that prevent wild Pokémon from running away, but I don't know if they exist in Legends.

Does Pokémon Legends Arceus have a way to prevent wild Pokémon from running away from a battle?

Comment: Anyway, saving before attempting to catch a shiny is the best strategy we have, since they are visible in the operworld now. And I feel you, I lost one recently, too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, NO.

Old games used to have moves like Mean Look, Block and Spiderweb which prevented the target from switching out or fleeing.

Similar moves were Clamp, Sand Tomb, Fire Spin, Whirlpool and Wrap that inflected damage while preventing switching and escape.

And none of these are present in Pokemon Legends: Arceus, so I really doubt this is possible.

I searched for the [whole attack list](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/attacks.shtml) with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://www.touchtapplay.com/how-to-stop-pokemon-from-running-away-in-pokemon-legends-arceus/), you can stun them to slow them down (or another stealth approach), but I don't think there is a way to completely guarantee them from running away.